# using a if statement to see if the user put in the correct string

Tags: c++, if-statement

Not sure how to make sure the user puts in the correct string in the console and then have it relate to the correct if statement. I'm also not sure how to assign damage values or armour values to agility, strength, intelligence so that they affect the character other then just a integer.

```
      class Character {
public:
    string name;
    string gender;
    string type;
    int strength;
    int agility;
    int intelligence;
    int level;
    int health;
    int experience;
    int mainweapon;
    int offhand;
    int chest;
    int legarmor;
    int gloves;
    int helmet;
    int gold;
    int faction;
};


int main()
{
    Character Charactername;
    Character Charactergender;
    Character Charactertype;
    Character Characteragility;
    Character Characterstrength;
    Character Characterintelligence;
    cout << "what is your name?\n";
    cin >> Charactername.name;
    cout << "Male or Female\n";
    cin >> Charactergender.gender;
    cout << "What class are you, Warrior, Mage or Rogue\n";
    cin >> Charactertype.type;
    cout << "Welcome to the Elysium " << Charactername.name;
    Sleep(5000);

    Character Characterhealth;
    Characterhealth.health = 100;
    if (Charactertype.type == "Warrior","warrior")
        Characteragility.agility = 6, Characterstrength.strength = 10, Characterintelligence.intelligence = 4;
    else if (Charactertype.type == "Mage","mage")
        Characteragility.agility = 4, Characterstrength.strength = 6, Characterintelligence.intelligence = 10;
    else if (Charactertype.type == "Rogue", "rogue")
        Characteragility.agility = 10, Characterstrength.strength = 4, Characterintelligence.intelligence = 6;
    else cout << "you have entered a invalid name" << main;
    cout << Characteragility.agility << endl << Characterstrength.strength << endl << Characterintelligence.intelligence;
    Sleep(2000);
};
```

Comment: Get yourself a good book and read it. You clearly don't understand what are you doing.

Comment: `if (Charactertype.type == "Warrior","warrior")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: i get that i dont know what i am doing im just trying to do something and its not that its producing an error its just not doing what i intended it to do that is why i posted it here because i cant manage to find out what im doing wrong ive been looking it up but obviously in the wrong places (im new to c++ and im just trying to learn it)

Comment: @Wolfsouls So what were your observations when you debugged that code? As mentioned  `if (Charactertype.type == "Warrior","warrior")` should probably be replaced by something like `if (Charactertype.type == "Warrior" || Charactertype.type == "warrior")`. You also might read up about the comma operator.

Comment: well when i run the program it has no errors it has a logic error in the if statement and that is doing the first if statement no matter what even if i put in "Mage" in the console it still prints out 6,10,4 always which is what i am trying to fix

Comment: nvm i see what you mean yea that worked

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
if (Charactertype.type == "Warrior","warrior")
```

does not do what you think it does. C++ uses && for and and || for or. So if you are trying to say if type is "Warrior" or type is "warrior", you should do

```
if(Charactertype.type == "Warrior" || Charactertype.type == "warrior")
{
  //do something
}
else if( something something)
{
  //do something else
}
```

you can do this exact same thing when you are inputting a string trough console and if it is incorrect input, you can ask the user to input the string again.

Also your code is a mess. Why do you have different class objects for different attributes ? The whole point of objects is to store the whole data in 1 object and not create different objects for each variable.You only need to declare a second Character object when you are talking about a different player for example.